# cert-manager automatic renewal isn't checking certificals with a due renewal time

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, lets-encrypt, rancher, cert-manager

I've been using cert manager for 87 days now and saw some certs which are due in 3 days (duration of 90 days) are not being renewed automatically. At first, the certificates weren't tagged with a `duration` or `renewBefore` spec. This should default to 90/30 according to the documentation.

I've already tried using cmctl to force renew, added the `duration` and `renewBefore` specs and spent a lot of time looking at the logs of all the CM pods. Since starting my debugging journey, I saw that the cert indeed got a `renewalTime` added to it. But the certificates are not being renewed at all. Could it be possible that cert manager isn't checking for certificates to renew?

I've got about 20 which are due this week, and ~100 this month so I would really like this auto renewal to work.

If any configuration is needed, I'll gladly provide additional info.

Comment: There was a bug in the renewal flow that was [fixed](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/4575) and check  at your cert's renew after/renew before dates it probably would have been affected.Try to upgrade to [v1.4.4](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/tag/v1.4.4), [v1.5.4](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/tag/v1.5.4) or [v1.6.0](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/tag/v1.6.0), hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: If not, follow the [link below](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/api-connect/10.0.1.x?topic=manager-automatic-renewal-cert) which might help you with the auto renewal process.